# Nice way to convert AxisDatatypes from the same .xsd

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, wsdl2java

I am looking for a possibility to convert two Axis Datatypes (generated by WSDL2Java) into each other. Both DataTypes consists of exactly the same Attributes because they are both from the same XSD.

The Problem is Axis generates them as Seperated Datatypes.

DataType1:

```
public static class AbstractAsynchronousResponse extends AbstractResponse implements org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBBean {

        /*
         * This type was generated from the piece of schema that had name =
         * AbstractAsynchronousResponse Namespace URI =
         * http://www.example.org/AllCallbackTypes Namespace Prefix = ns2
         */
.........}
```

DataType2:

```
public static class AbstractAsynchronousResponse extends AbstractResponse implements org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBBean {

        /*
         * This type was generated from the piece of schema that had name =
         * AbstractAsynchronousResponse Namespace URI =
         * http://www.example.org/AllCallbackTypes Namespace Prefix = ns2
         */
.........}
```

Now I want to do Something like this:

```
AbstractAsynchronousResponse1 response1 = new AbstractAsynchronousResponse1();
AbstractAsynchronousResponse2 response2 = (AbstractAsynchronousResponse2) response1;
```

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Method I created to solve this Problem. However this isn't really nice but it works.

```
/**
     * This will cast an {@link ADBBean} implementation to another
     * {@link ADBBean}, but the Implementation will be a subClass of
     * <b>parentLocationOfSourceClass</b>.<br>
     * This only is possible because of the structure of all ADBBean
     * implementations created by <code>Axis2 ADB-Databinding</code>. If you
     * cange the Databinding you probably have to adapt this Method.
     * 
     * @param inputADBBean
     *            An ADBBean Implementation created by
     *            <code>Axis2 ADB-Databinding</code>
     * @param parentLocationOfSourceClass
     *            This is meant to be the <code>ClientStub</code> Class created
     *            by <code>Axis2 ADB-Databinding</code>. The Implementation of
     *            the <code>inputADBBean</code> has to be available with the
     *            same name in the <code>ClientStub</code>
     * @return An {@link ADBBean} implementation defined as SubClass of the
     *         <code>ClientStub</code> Class created by
     *         <code>Axis2 ADB-Databinding</code>
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static ADBBean castADBBean(ADBBean inputADBBean, String parentLocationOfSourceClass) throws Exception {
        Class clazz = CallbackResponsePoolClient.getClassForParentLocation(inputADBBean, parentLocationOfSourceClass);
        ADBBean outputADBBean = CallbackResponsePoolClient.getInstanceForADBBean(clazz);
        for (Method method : outputADBBean.getClass().getMethods()) {
            String methodName = method.getName();
            if (methodName.startsWith("set")) {
                CallbackResponsePoolClient.logger.debug("Found a setter: " + methodName);
                String getterName = methodName.replaceFirst("set", "get");
                Object arg = inputADBBean.getClass().getMethod(getterName).invoke(inputADBBean);
                // We need to check if arg lives in the namespace:
                // org.example.www.callbackresponsepoolinterface
                // This will happen if we have nested Objects. E.g.
                // EndpointType inside of EndpointResponse
                // TODO: instanceof ADBBean could lead to problems, maybe
                // sometimes we don't want to cast an ADBBean, but I can't think
                // a scenario right now
                if (arg instanceof ADBBean) {
                    arg = CallbackResponsePoolClient.castADBBean((ADBBean) arg, parentLocationOfSourceClass);
                }
                // We also need to handle Arrays of ADBBeans. See above
                if (arg instanceof ADBBean[]) {
                    Class innputClass = ((ADBBean[]) arg).getClass().getComponentType();
                    // Better Create a new Object, because arg[0], can get you
                    // an Exception for an empty Array
                    ADBBean inputArrObj = CallbackResponsePoolClient.getInstanceForADBBean(innputClass);
                    Class outputArrClass = CallbackResponsePoolClient.getClassForParentLocation(inputArrObj, parentLocationOfSourceClass);
                    Object outputArray = Array.newInstance(outputArrClass, ((ADBBean[]) arg).length);
                    for (int i = 0; i < Array.getLength(arg); i++) {
                        Array.set(outputArray, i, CallbackResponsePoolClient.castADBBean((ADBBean) Array.get(arg, i), parentLocationOfSourceClass));
                    }
                    arg = outputArray;
                }

                method.invoke(outputADBBean, arg);
            }
        }

        return outputADBBean;
    }

    private static Class getClassForParentLocation(ADBBean inputADBBean, String parentLocationOfSourceClass) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return Class.forName(parentLocationOfSourceClass + "$" + inputADBBean.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }

    private static ADBBean getInstanceForADBBean(Class clazz) throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        Constructor constructor = clazz.getConstructor();
        return (ADBBean) constructor.newInstance();
    }
```